# Can AIC be used to select the best model with multiply imputed data (MICE)?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, data-imputation, mice, information-criteria

I have used the `mice()` package in R to impute some missing values and create a pooled linear regression model. I have also created another version but this time with interaction. I want to use AIC to select which is the best model but I can't figure a way to do this.

If I create both models using the non-imputed data with missing values (20% missing) and use AIC to select the best model, will this be applicable to the imputed models? Or will it likely be inaccurate because it's based on a version of the data with missing values?

Basically, can I use AIC to select the best model before imputing the data, and then use the AIC result to create a model with the imputed data? If not, is there a way I can use AIC to select the best model with imputed data created with `mice()`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the prerequisites for any information criterion (IC) to be used for goodness of fit is that the two models must be based on the **exact same data**. If there is any reason to believe that the imputation will result in different values between the models, then you cannot use any of the *IC family for testing goodness of fit. If, however, you run a single imputation first and then construct models with and without interaction *on the exact same data* then you can rely on the theoretical properties of IC to select between them.

Also, this question is best asked on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), the stack exchange for statistics.

Comment: Multiple imputation involves, in the usual practice, of using Rubin's rule for getting an imputation-corrected covariance matrix.  This does not give you a log likelihood as needed for AIC.  Besides that model selection is usually not a good idea as the data seldom possess adequate information to allow you to select the "right" variables.